# How to create select in emberJs and add data to it with event handling

Tags: ember.js, ember-select

I want to create a combobox (select) in emberjs. I want to add few records to that combobox and then do event handling for it. I am new to EmberJs and finding it difficult to add a combobox with event handling. I used this fiddle http://jsbin.com/ofONeQ/14/edit but getting error saying

```
DEPRECATION: Do not specify `content` on a Controller, use `model` instead.
```

Comment: Here is a cleaned up version of what you were trying to do, hope it helps. http://jsbin.com/ofONeQ/96/

Answer (score 0):

Use this fiddle. it contains the implementation :  http://jsbin.com/dokamuliqicu/1/